# Detect reload browser alert on angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

sometimes on angularJS js, I have got "reload" alert from the browser with the message "are you sure you want to reload the page"?

I am using model but its happen also if I'm not opening the modals, and also I am using ui-notification maybe it's related to them

how can I find or debug it and disable it at all?

Comment: decide wheather its angular or angularJS. It is angularjs then you can use routeChangeStart, if its angular then you can use Guards : canDeActive.

Comment: Try this one, In app.js file add an alert("reload"), may this work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS window.onbeforeunload in one controller is being triggered on another controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533513/angularjs-window-onbeforeunload-in-one-controller-is-being-triggered-on-another)

Comment: @MayurShah Custom messages are deprecated on the latest Crome&FF versions (And perhaps Microsoft Edge - But who cares about that browser anyway)